# Creating Queues for messages

Tags: c#, queue, message

I have a method which creates JSON messages every two seconds. I want to bulk those messages until a bulk contains 100 messages and then send the messages. The issue I am running in is in creating this queue - i.e. each time a json message is created it should be added to the queue.

Any ideas how to do it best ?

Thanks in advance.

Currently I am trying to store those elements in a list by using lists:

```
List<string> ABC = new List<string>();
```

I expect to have a method which adds up all messages. Currently each time a new list is created.

Comment: "a method which adds up all messages" - you mean something like `ABC.Add(message)`? Because that method actually exists.

Comment: How do you get the messages from the provider method? This method is used in what type of application? please be more specific

Comment: Question solved. Did a mistake. :-)